# How can i get the links in my navigation bar to be displayed horizontally? Flexbox doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, css

Not sure why my setup isn't working. with the links set to `display:flex;`, shouldn't they be displayed next to each other instead of on top of each other? Right now I have `<p>Test</p>` on the left, and my links stacked on top of each other to the right.

**Here's the html:**

```
<body>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                        <p>Test</p>
                </div>
                <div class="link-wrapper">
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Portfolio</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Styles</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

**and the css:**

```
 * {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

.link-wrapper a {
        text-decoration: none;
}

.link-wrapper li {
                list-style: none;
}

.nav-wrapper {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 8vh;
}

.link-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        width: 30%;
        justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided property flex to `link-wrapper` class but `<li></li>` tags are under `<ul><ul>` so either give ul a class `link-wrapper` or do something like this.

```css
* {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

.link-wrapper a {
        text-decoration: none;
}

.link-wrapper li {
                list-style: none;
}

.nav-wrapper {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 8vh;
}

.link-wrapper ul {
        display: flex;
        width: 30%;
        justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="logo">
                        <p>Test</p>
                </div>
                <div class="link-wrapper">
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>About</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Portfolio</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Styles</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Contact</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```